# Referring to text fields with tags

Tags: ios

I have an app that makes 20 text fields that are called textField and have tags 1 to 20 assigned to them. I don't know what I should replace the ? with so the first textField gets selected when I open the app.

```
[? becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work your tags need to be unique - I.e. The only subview with a tag of 1 is your first text field (it doesn't matter what type of view, no other can have the same tag):

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:1] becomeFirstResponder];
```

Assuming that the text fields are all added to `self.view`.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing view elements(textView) using tag is the easiest approach I have seen.

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:TAG];
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```